# Manually resize WinRE partition (Windows 10 Home)

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I would like to do the procedure outlined in Microsoft KB5028997.
I would like my WinRE to become 1G.

But I am not 100% sure I understand the instructions for that. Only 99%, so I would like to confirm some things:

- Where do I set the size? Do I just replace the 250 with 1024 minus the size of my current WinRE (which is 522 as reported by Disk Management)?
- Can someone who did the procedure confirm that I wont lose my OS partition data if all goes well?
- What if the OS partition has data stored near the 'end'? Will random files risk being destroyed by the resize? Or will they be moved to places 'not near end' so they fit inside the new size?
- In theory, what would happen if my OS partition was nearly full, and I tried to make it smaller?

The reason I want to do it is the cumulative KB5034203, which sadly contains the KB5034441, which wont install due to too small WinRE.

I do not want to install 3rd party partition tools, so no reason to suggest that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where do I set the size?

You shrink the system partition then recreate the WinRE partition in the unallocated partition that is created. The  first step in the procedures have you disable the WinRE with the command `reagentc /disable`

> Do I just replace the 250 with 1024 minus the size of my current WinRE (which is 522 as reported by Disk Management)?

How much you shrink the system partition by is entirely up to you.  It also depends on the size of the current WinRE partition.

> Can someone who did the procedure confirm that I wont lose my OS partition data if all goes well?

Shrinkng the size of the partition is fairly harmless.  You should of course have a backup of your most important files before you perform any modifications, especially if you are modifying the disk's partition table.

> What if the OS partition has data stored near the 'end'?

Windows won't let you shrink the partition if that's the case.

> Will random files risk being destroyed by the reize?

The lost of files due to shrinking of a partition is unlikely to happen. Keep in mind, had the update worked instead of failing, your WinRE partition would already be larger.

> will they be moved to places 'not near end' so they fit inside the new size?

You will have to resolve files being at the end of the disk before you will be able to shrink the system partition. Windows does this automatically with optimization on SSDs and defragmentation on mechanical HDDs.

> In theory, what would happen if my OS partition was nearly full, and I tried to make it smaller?

You would only be able to shrink the partition by the amount of free space you have available.  You should NOT do shrink the system partition and put it in a state where there is not enough forespace.  **If you are low on space, you should absolutely not perform any action to shrink the system partition until you resolve that problem.**

> The reason I want to do it is the cumulative KB5034203, which sadly contains the KB5034441, which wont install due to too small WinRE.

If you don't feel comfortable shrinking the system partition you should wait till Microsoft released an update that will superceed KB5034441.